# How do I get a facebook user's most recent messages with another user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messages

I'm working on a web application in which I show the last time the current user (who authenticates with FB and supplies all relevant permissions) user interacted with another user. Example, my ID is 1526632 and would like to find the date of the last message sent between me and another facebook user (either by username, or id #).

I've been reading through their API and it seems this permission existed in version [2.4 of the Chat API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/inbox) but was since deprecated. Is there a new way for developers to get this information somehow?

My guess is this is not possible via the graph API. Assuming this is true, does facebook have unpublished IMAP access to a user's inbox? Or any other creative ways I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Chat API is gone, as you have found out already. There is no replacement, what you want to achieve is not possible in any way. The user inbox is off limits now, i´m afraid.